# Is there a colored REPL for Clojure?

Tags: clojure, colors, syntax-highlighting, read-eval-print-loop

I'd like to get a colored REPL for clojure code, similar to what you can do with IRB for Ruby.

Are there any libraries or settings for user.clj that provide automatic coloring of the REPL?

Example IRB:

[image]

Comment: That's pretty! How can I get that for SLIME REPL?

Comment: @Zolomon - see my answer below.

Comment: Similar question: [What to do to make `lein repl` colorful?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19500353/578288)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I do not know of any way to have the basic Clojure REPL, as started by something like `java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main`, do syntax highlighting. If, however, you use Emacs & SLIME (the development environment of choice of a great part of the Clojure community!), then you can have the SLIME REPL highlight syntax like `clojure-mode` does.

First, you'll have to lift some code from the `clojure-mode` function (defined towards the top of `clojure-mode.el`):

```
;;; all code in this function lifted from the clojure-mode function
;;; from clojure-mode.el
(defun clojure-font-lock-setup ()
  (interactive)
  (set (make-local-variable 'lisp-indent-function)
       'clojure-indent-function)
  (set (make-local-variable 'lisp-doc-string-elt-property)
       'clojure-doc-string-elt)
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-multiline) t)

  (add-to-list 'font-lock-extend-region-functions
               'clojure-font-lock-extend-region-def t)

  (when clojure-mode-font-lock-comment-sexp
    (add-to-list 'font-lock-extend-region-functions
                 'clojure-font-lock-extend-region-comment t)
    (make-local-variable 'clojure-font-lock-keywords)
    (add-to-list 'clojure-font-lock-keywords
                 'clojure-font-lock-mark-comment t)
    (set (make-local-variable 'open-paren-in-column-0-is-defun-start) nil))

  (setq font-lock-defaults
        '(clojure-font-lock-keywords    ; keywords
          nil nil
          (("+-*/.<>=!?$%_&~^:@" . "w")) ; syntax alist
          nil
          (font-lock-mark-block-function . mark-defun)
          (font-lock-syntactic-face-function
           . lisp-font-lock-syntactic-face-function))))
```

Then add it to the `slime-repl-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-mode nil)
            (clojure-font-lock-setup)
            (font-lock-mode t)))
```

Et voilà, next time you connect to the SLIME REPL you'll have `clojure-mode` syntax highlighting available. If you use SLIME for Common Lisp too, you'll want to tweak this so it doesn't try to do Clojure highlighting with CL. Also, this is just a first approximation; one thing it sort of breaks is prompt highlighting (the `namespace>` thing will not be highlighted anymore). I'm not a proficient `font-lock` hacker by any stretch of the imagination, though, so I'll leave it at that. :-)

Comment: Oh, by the way, this really *replaces* SLIME REPL highlighting with clojure-mode highlighting... There are some useful things about the usual REPL highlighting which one might miss when using this. Hopefully at some point this can be refined to make this less of a trade-off.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not an Emacs user, but this does look cool.

Comment: @thnetos: Thanks! @All whom this may concern: I've put the code in a Gist here: http://gist.github.com/337280 -- the current version includes two `defadvice` s to make the prompt and printouts on `*out*` be highlighted as they usually are in SLIME REPL, while everything else still gets clojure-mode highlights.

Comment: The most up-to-date version of this code is now part of [Phil Hagelberg](http://technomancy.us/)'s new [durendal](http://github.com/technomancy/durendal) project.

Comment: CIDER's REPL has built-in colouring support (although it doesn't work quite like this, as expressions get font-locked after being evaluated).

Answer (score 28):

Rather late to the party, here, but you can get this from using the Leiningen plugin [Ultra](https://github.com/venantius/ultra) (which also has support for colorized stacktraces and pretty-printed test output), or by adding [Whidbey](https://github.com/greglook/whidbey) to your list of Leiningen plugins instead.

Sample Ultra REPL:[image]

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to color the prompt and you are using [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) (which you should), you can use `:repl-options` and [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```clojure
:repl-options {:prompt (fn [ns]
                         (str "\033[1;32m"
                              ns "=>"
                              "\033[0m "))}
```

References:

- [GitHub – technomancy/leiningen – `sample.project.clj`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/sample.project.clj#L334)
- [roguejs.com – “Console colors in node.js”, posted 2011](http://web.archive.org/web/20130625035830/http://roguejs.com/2011-11-30/console-colors-in-node-js)

Comment: To make this apply to your user rather than a single project, add this to `~/.lein/profiles.clj`

Comment: Put this in `~/.lein/profiles.clj` for global colored repl: `{:user {:repl-options {:prompt (fn [ns] (str "\033[1;32m" ns "=>" "\033[0m "))}}}`

Comment: When adding this to `~/.lein/profiles.clj`, put the config within the `:repl` profile, instead of `:user`. So the structure is `{:repl {:repl-options {:prompt …}}}`. This ensures the config is only defined for `lein repl`, not for other subcommands like `lein test`.

Answer (score 5):

- Install Emacs 24
- Install [Emacs Starter Kit v2](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit#readme)
- `M-x package-install` -> `starter-kit-lisp`
- Add to init.el: `(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'clojure-mode-font-lock-setup)`
- Install [Swank for Clojure](https://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure#readme)
- Open your Clojure project and `M-x clojure-jack-in`

[image: Emacs REPL]

Comment: this should be updated to use https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el instead of swank-clojure

Answer (score 2):

Some coloring have REPL in VimClojure.

Answer (score 2):

Try out Light Table Playground by Chris Granger.  It is the first part of more ambitous multi language IDE.

It has a color Clojure REPL that does real time evaluations and display for entire blocks of code.

http://www.chris-granger.com/lighttable/

You can see a higher level view of the project here:

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ibdknox/light-table

Comment: Great project, but sadly inactive now

Answer (score 2):

[CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider) users can obtain a coloured REPL by adding the following to their config:

```
(setq cider-repl-use-clojure-font-lock t)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse [Counterclockwise](http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/) REPL provides full syntax colouring (including rainbow bracket colouring).

I believe it uses [nREPL](https://github.com/aav/tools.nrepl) under the hood.

Comment: Yes it exactly uses nRepl but employs a custom coloring strategy that of course can be configured (contributor@here)

Answer (score 1):

If you're an Intellij user, the excellent [Cursive](https://cursiveclojure.com/) is a great choice, and provides pretty colours that you can customise:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get your REPL output colorized try [repl-color](https://github.com/razum2um/repl-color)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try LightTable, it lets you select the functions and run instantly.