# Ways to start Clojure REPL?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

Name the ways you know to start the Clojure REPL. What is your favourite ? Does it highlight things for you ?

I know of :
1. NetBeans IDE with the Enclojure plugin, and
2. the Leiningen shell script : lein repl

No favorite for me so far, and I'd certainly like some colors.

What else ?

Answer (score 7):

Syntax-highlighted Clojure REPL is entirely possible in Emacs -- I wrote the necessary code in response to a very old question here on SO: [Is there a colored REPL for Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474804/is-there-a-colored-repl-for-clojure) I have since tweaked it to handle the prompt and printouts from the Clojure process properly; the updated version is available in [this Gist](http://gist.github.com/337280). Note that it's meant to augment the SLIME REPL and that the most recent version relies on a reasonably fresh clojure-mode. I was going to package this properly so that slimey Clojurians can just drop it into their Emacs configs... might just do it sometime soon.

As another option, I seem to have an extremely vague recollection of VimClojure's REPL highlighting user input a long time ago... I definitely could be wrong about this, though.

Oh, and since you're curious about other possible ways to start Clojure REPLs -- all the IDE plugins provide their own REPLs; you could use the regular inferior-lisp-mode in Emacs; `java -jar clojure.jar` starts a REPL with the current working directory on the classpath; if you embed swank-clojure in your app, you can start REPL servers from within it; VimClojure provides a nice REPLing experience inside Vim (and I believe it provides an equivalent of <kbd>M-x slime-connect</kbd>, though, once again, I haven't used it in a pretty long time); you can use Leiningen or clojure-maven-plugin to start stand-alone REPLs or swank instances (I'd expect other Clojure-aware build tools to be capable of this too); [cljr](http://github.com/liebke/cljr) can start console REPLs, REPLs packaged in a Swing window and swank instances; there might be more.

Comment: The most up-to-date version of the "clojure-mode font lock for SLIME REPL" code is now part of [Phil Hagelberg](http://technomancy.us/)'s new [durendal](http://github.com/technomancy/durendal) project.

Answer (score 2):

You can start one with [Redcar Editor](http://redcareditor.com/) using the Enclojure REPL.  This [blog post](http://redcareditor.com/blog/2010/08/redcar-039/) has a screenshot of it in action.  It does support colored syntax highlighting.  Redcar support for clojure in general isn't great right now, but I am working on improving the experience.  If you try it out, let me know what you think.

Comment: Oh, this is cool! +1 for improving the Clojure tooling space. :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Cljr](http://github.com/liebke/cljr)
 is a Clojure REPL and package manager by David Liebke.

It meets the need for a repl for "just trying stuff out". A plain command line repl, a swing repl and a swank server (for use with Emacs SLIME mode) can be started with easily managed clojure and java dependencies available.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm in Emacs or have an Emacs sitting open somewhere, I typically just use SLIME connected to a swank server. I get a highlighted REPL that way and all the power of Emacs right there in my REPL.

When I don't have Emacs handy, I use [cake](http://github.com/ninjudd/cake) to start an REPL in a terminal. I don't get highlighting like this, but you can get excellent multiline support and even completion.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start Clojure REPL (assumes clojure.jar and clojure-contrib.jar are in /opt/clojure
# Don't remember where I got this originally

# GUI mode
if [ "$TERM" == "dumb" ]; then
    gnome-terminal -t Clojure -x $0 $* &
    exit
fi

breakchars="(){}[],^%$#@\"\";:''|\\"
rlwrap --remember -c -b "$breakchars" \
    java -Djava.ext.dirs=/opt/clojure clojure.main -i $HOME/.clojurerc --repl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little hack to "inject" a remote Clojure repl into your running application (with remote debugging enabled, but otherwise unmodified):
https://github.com/wirde/swank-inject