# Syntax highlighting in Lein REPL?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I want to configure Lein so that I see a colored REPL, like Emacs' nREPL. How can I do this?

I couldn't find any help on Google. Do I need to learn Bash scripting first?

Comment: Similar question: [Is there a colored REPL for Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2474804/)

Answer (score 16):

[Ultra](https://github.com/venantius/ultra), “a Leiningen plugin for a superior development environment”, highlights syntax well for REPL output, among other useful things.

[image: screenshot of Ultra]
At the moment, there are no plugins or stand-alone REPLs that highlight syntax for input.

Answer (score 3):

[Whidbey](https://github.com/greglook/whidbey) “pretty-prints colored REPL values by default”, using [Puget](https://github.com/greglook/puget) to do the actual pretty-printing. Whidbey’s README seems to indicate that you can install it for all Leiningen projects simply by adding the following `:plugins` value to your user [profile](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md) at `~/.lein/profiles.clj`:

```clojure
{:user {:plugins [[mvxcvi/whidbey "0.5.0"]]}}
```

Though I personally couldn’t get it to work, no matter what I tried.

You can also look at the [Colors](https://github.com/trptcolin/reply/wiki/Colors) page on REPLy’s wiki. ([REPLy](https://github.com/trptcolin/reply) is the REPL built-in to Leiningen 2, and it integrates with nREPL.) For now, all that wiki page contains is a link to [Whidbey](https://github.com/greglook/whidbey), but it might be updated in the future.

Comment: Using the above works for me, but the **highlighting is very limited** and only applies to the output.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to seem rude with the editing and the bold font.

Comment: @Josh Don’t worry, your edit wasn’t rude. I can see that the context makes the code block easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Bash for this at all – the shell only starts processes on the command-line, but they can be written in any language.

I don't think [nREPL](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl) or its terminal client which is integrated into Leiningen as lein repl, [REPL-y](https://github.com/trptcolin/reply/), provide any support for syntax colouring themselves. So the most promising approach is probably to fork REPL-y and integrate syntax colouring into it yourself, probably based on some existing syntax colouring solution for Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

From emacs client you can try [emacs-live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live)

https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live#colour

> Colour
>
> Colour highlighting in two flavours - cyberpunk and gandalf. Use
>   color-theme-cyberpunk and color-theme-gandalf to switch between the
>   two themes. Currently cyberpunk has seen more love - patch requests
>   accepted for appropriate improvements to Gandalf.